# Étiquettes sur les articles / Tags for articles

Tags: discussion, tags

Les questions portant sur l'usage et la grammaire des articles sont identifiées par l'étiquette [articles](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/articles).

Je me demande si nous devrions créer des étiquettes plus précises, comme [article-défini](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/article-d%c3%a9fini), [article-indéfini](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/article-ind%c3%a9fini), [absence-d-article](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/absence-d-article), etc. Les articles sont des mots très difficiles à chercher, on ne peut guère que compter sur les étiquettes pour trouver une question qui porte spécifiquement sur le sujet.

À titre de comparaison, [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags) a plusieurs étiquettes: [articles](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/articles), [definite-articles](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definite-articles), [indefinite-articles](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indefinite-articles), [zero-article](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zero-article).

---

Questions about articles are currently tagged [articles](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/articles). Should we have more specific tags such as [definite-article](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definite-article), [indefinite-article](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indefinite-article), [zero-article](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zero-article), etc.? Articles are very hard to search for, one pretty much has to rely on labels to find relevant questions.

Answer (score 2):

Oui.

Le seul souci que je vois serait qu'avec la politique actuelle d'évitement des tags hiérarchiques, on ne pourrait plus chercher parmi toutes les questions traitant d'[article](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/article) en général, mais je n'ai pas l'impression que ce serait un si gros problème.

Comment: Pourquoi déterminant? Quand on regarde *la*, *un*, etc. dans un dictionnaire, il indique « article », donc c'est ce que les gens vont avoir naturellement tendance à chercher.

Comment: Parce que c'est 1. l'appellation courante en linguistique contemporaine (plus personne n'utilise *article* à ma connaissance) 2. l'appellation majoritairement utilisée dans les programmes scolaires (au moins [en France](http://eduscol.education.fr/pid23199/ecole-elementaire-et-college.html), IIRC au Québec aussi)

Comment: Mais les dictionnaires utilisent *article*.

Comment: Je n'ai pas dit le contraire. C'est un choix à faire. Je préfère *déterminant*, mais je comprends pourquoi on peut préférer *article*. Tu penses que ça vaut le coup de faire un meta dédié ?

Comment: Oui, je pense qu'il faudrait un fil séparé sur méta, où tu expliquerais un peu plus ton point de vue. À commencer par une définition, parce que moi, à l'école, on m'a appris que les articles sont une catégorie de déterminants, l'autre catégorie étant les adjectifs.

Comment: Ça marche, je vire ça de ce post et je prépare un autre fil (soonish)